# monjaro уходит в сон, через время выключается

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

Поставил monjaro, все хорошо, все радует.

После того как я закрываю крышку ноутбука: если сразу открыть - да, он вышел из сна, все приложения остались на месте, включился быстро; но если подождать какое-то время и открыть крышку позже, то он как-будто перезагружается: начинает с приветствия, проходит пост, проверяет файловую систему  и так далее.

Как это можно исправить ?

Начал пытаться подружиться с linux не так давно, поэтому я не знаю куда капать. Так же прошу прощения за небольшой объем информации, не знаю, что может быть полезно. Если нужно что-то добросить - докину.

Ноутбук: Acer apire e15 (e5-575g-34ps)

```
System:    Kernel: 4.9.53-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.2.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.24.3 (Gtk 3.22.21) Distro: Manjaro Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал для своего Travelmate гибридный сон при закрытии крышки.
Он вырубается также пр долгом сне, но при открытии крышки загружается на тот момент на котором остался. Правда есть проблемы с клавиатурой - не просыпается.

Один способ: в /etc/systemd/logind.conf выставить `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`. В этом варианте будет уходить в сон на диск.

Второй способ выставить там же `HandleLidSwitch=hybrid-sleep`. В этом случае если будет обычный сон, но с возможностью проснуться с диска.

Еще стоит посмотреть параметры энергосбережения в BIOS.

Comment: если найдете как просыпать клавиатуру - расскажите)

Comment: Попробовал первый способ. Режим сна изменился. Вечером оставлял ноутбук закрытым,  утром открыл - работает как сон, раньше даже в этом случае работало некорректно. После начал собираться, сложил в сумку. Через часа 3 я его достал и опять, он выключился пока был в сумке. Может быть какая-то защита от ударов (слышал, что где-то такое есть). Еще сегодня попробую второй способ, но не думаю, что это может что-то изменить. На счет BIOS я не видел нужных настроек. Попробую обновить, хотя ноут новый, маловероятно, что версия биоса старая. 

P.S. на счет клавиатуры видел где-то на форумах.

Comment: ну так сон - это ж хорошо)

Comment: помогло, я первый раз допустил ошибку в файле. все работает, спасибо.